# Variables not showing in Firebug

Tags: javascript

I'm still getting to grips with some of the JavaScript variable handling and I'm a bit confused over this.

I have a variable declared in a file like this:

```
(function (myControls, $, undefined) {

    var selectedLifeArea;
    ...
```

But when looking for these in Firebug they aren't listed under the myControls "namespace" as I expected, only the functions are listed.  Why is that?

Comment: ...maybe because your code is wrapped in what seems to be an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)?

Comment: So surely it should be listed within that scope?

Comment: It sounds like your understanding of "scope" is flawed.

Comment: I think that's pretty obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrapped in it's own scope.

Try adding some breaks in the js debugger, then you can read the variables.

---

Here is a brief description:

```
var globalVariable;

(function () {

    var localVariable;

    // can access both `globalVariable` and `localVariable`
    ...
)();

// can only access `globalVariable`
```

Comment: I get that scope thing, what I don't understand is why it's not listed in Firebug INSIDE that scope either, Firebog didn't list a myControls.selectedLifeArea

Comment: @Jammer because there is no such thing as `myControls.selectedLifeArea`

Comment: @Jammer Why would there be a `myControls.selectedLifeArea`? `selectedLifeArea` is a local variable, not a property of `myControls`...and `myControls` is just a parameter. Maybe you need to post more of your code

Comment: So how can I make this a property?

Comment: @Jammer That is a completely different question.

Comment: @Jammer Well, by setting it as a property -- `myControls.selectedLifeArea = ...;`

Comment: OK, this seems to have worked myControls.selectedLifeArea = {};